# How to save Russian character in Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle, utf-8

I have a sample data something like below,

```
212 Морская рыба ООО
213 Мрия фирма ООО
214 МТН ООО
215 Онега ООО
216 Плеском ООО
217 Русмар ООО
218 Технолог ООО
219 Ферум ООО
220 Ширван ООО
221 Актория ООО
```

After inserting into the Table, the value of the Russians character are replaced by the placeholder

```
¿¿¿¿¿¿¿ ¿¿¿¿ ¿¿¿
```

I thought of using `AL32UTF8`, but I didn't find this value inside the SQL Developer.

Please tell me how can I save the data into table or how to change the `UTF-8` setting inside the SQL Developer

Comment: `INSERT INTO YourTable (Column1, Column2) values (222, N'Актория ООО')` - worked for sql server, think it's same in oracle

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49916168

Comment: @Veljko89 No, it's not working for Oracle

Comment: Answer on the link says it does

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks you. It works for me. You can post this as answer, really helps me